# How to save a list as a file in python continuously? (every element contains a data-frame)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

How can I save a list that contains data-frame as every element in python? Also, I need this continuously (appending the list), so in every iteration of my loop, I add an element to the list. This new element contains a data-frame.

```
for i in x:
## (some calculations (this takes time. approximately every 1 or 2 seconds, I have a new output (data-frame).)

## I need to save my results here (it's a list contains many data-frames.
```

This is running all day, and the size of the file is large, so It's important to do this efficiently (the size of final file should be small, and the process should be fast).

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to save all dataframes in your list to your system?

Comment: @MohitMotwani Yes. I want to do this. But to increase the performance, I need to this continuously in approximately every 1 second (this depends on my calculation time).

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dataframes in a list, you can use the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function of the dataframe to save them as csv:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4] #here dfs is a list containing different dataframes

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_csv(f'df{i}.csv')
```

If you're using < python 3.6, replace last line with:

```
df.to_csv('df{}.csv'.format(str(i))
```

How long it takes to save the dataframe, really depends on the size of the dataframe.

Comment: hmm I'm confused why my solution won't work for you. Is it the speed and space?

Comment: I'm just thinking about the best solution (the fastest one with the smallest size). I'll try this one.

Comment: Also, I think your code doesn't append data to the file and generate a new one. As a result, for every iteration (1~2 second), we're creating a new file

Comment: My code assumes that you already have the dataframes in a list. I don't have enough information to add the dataframes to the list

Comment: In every iteration, I'm adding an element to this list and I want to append this new data to the last list and save it continuously.